# Rails 3 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

After migrate on Rails 3, I have error "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)"

For line:

```
<%== auto_link(raw(simple_format(h(comment.comment))), :all, :target => '_blank') -%>
```

Backtrace:

```
app/views/logs/_entry.html.erb:94:in `raw'
app/views/logs/_entry.html.erb:94:in
```

I got this error only on Production server

Comment: "<%==" it's similarly to "<%= raw(..."

Answer (score 0):

The helper `auto_link` [has been removed in Rails 3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/81cfbf4146d3c5a58054b64112b8ce196f2fc061). You need to install the Gem separately to use it. Also, make sure to check the correct method invocation.

Also, you should use `<%=`, not `<%==`.